# miktex-makepk: PK font Alegreya-Regular-lf-t1--base could not be created

Tags: errors, pdftex

I just want to use Alegreya font with pdflatex. i had a question about  an error before and got an answer. But it gives another error now. what should i do.

error message:

> miktex-makepk: PK font Alegreya-Regular-lf-t1--base could not be created.

in log file:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file Alegreya-Regular-lf-t1--base): Font Alegreya-
>   Regular-lf-t1--base at 657 not found
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Alegreya} %% Option 'black' gives heavier bold face 
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\AlegreyaOsF #1}}

\begin{document}
This is giving an error.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine for me in a current miktex 2.9. If your miktex is current then you probably have user map files, they are not updated when you install packages as admin. Run as user in a command line window `updmap`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: it happens that MiKTeX installs a package without running updmap.exe. Is that due to the fact that I do have a personal updmap.cfg? I think the updmap.cfg in the main root should have been updated and updmap.exe should have run on installation. But maybe I missed something…

Comment: @Bernard: personal updmap.cfg is not a problem. But if you run (e.g. with on-the-fly) installation once updmap as user then you create user map files, and these take preference above the admin map files. From then on you will have to run updmap as user when you install a font. updmap --admin will have no effect.

Comment: @Ulrike: I must say I have some difficulties with these concepts – probably because I first installed MiKTeX as administrator, asking for an installation for any user, and so thinking that the fastest way to update for everybody was to update as administrator. Besides, I'm not sure that running updmap.exe --admin is quite the same as running updmap.exe ‘from the command line as administrator’. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bernard: user settings wins over admins settings. If I change the background color in my account I overwrite the default settings of the admin. If the admin change the defaults later this will not affect my background color. And the same is true in miktex: if the user has overwritten the default font installation or installed a package it the user who has to manage it from there on. Check always also as user if there are updates.

Comment: @Ulrike: I can understand that. But what I do not understand is the fact that if a font is installed by the administrator _a priori_  for all users, why wouldn't psfonts.map and friends be updated for each user?

Comment: @Bernard because an admin can't change user files. The admin can define defaults (e.g. a general psfonts.map in the CommonData-tree of miktex) and update them but if the user creates its own psfonts. map in his UserData-tree it will be found first and the admin has no power to change it. And this is good so: if a user wants something special, the admin should not overwrite it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dvips.map and friends do not know about Alegreya, so instead of loading type 1 fonts, MiKTeX tries to make bitmaps and doesn't know how to make them.

Check if you have a text file named updmap.cfg in `C:\Users\Your_name\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config`. If not, create one. Add the following lines in that file:

> ```
> Map Alegreya.map
> ```

Then  execute as administrator this command line:

> ```
> updmap.exe -verbose
> ```

The `-verbose` switch is there to check what's happening. That's all. You can check everything's OK by looking at the contents of `psfonts.map`, in `C:\Users\Your_name\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config`. It should contain references to Alegreya.

Alternatively, you can compile with XeLateX or LuaLaTeX: you have to remove  `inputenc` loading, save you document in UTF-8 format (no `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`!) and write these lines in your preamble

```
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\setmainfont{Alegreya}
```

*Addendum:*  there seems to be a typo in line 233 of (MiKTeX's version of) `alegreya.sty`, which begins with:

```
\def*\useosf{...
```

and should begin with

```
\def\useosf{...
```

Comment: Only worked when I executed `updmap.exe` as normal user, i.e., without `--admin` (for the `xcharter` package). Yay.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation and pointing where to look! even after 2 years of this question, it was useful for me :-)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem but with the Classico font. My error message was

`FATAL miktex-makemf - The URWClassico-Bold-lf-t1--base source file could not be found`

followed by

`FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font URWClassico-Bold-lf-t1--base could not be created.`

I solved it by following the instructions at https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html under "4. Font map files: telling TeX about the new font"

In short, run `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`, add `Map <mapfile>` (in my case `Map Classico.map`) to the file, run `initexmf --mkmaps` and finally `initexmf --update-fndb`.

Comment: Using this method, I was able to install other fonts as well, having assumed that FontName.map is the right syntax. Is it always the case? For instance, Gentium is the font, so Gentium.map goes into the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the MiTex console and start as administrator. Then open the command prompt and enter

updmap.exe -verbose

Comment: This answer was already given just above yours…