# Error when trying to use Roboto font with pdftex

Tags: beamer, fonts, pdftex

I'm trying to use the Roboto font in a beamer presentation, built with pdftex. I installed the roboto package, but when trying to build, I get the following error:

> Trying to make PK font Roboto-Light-lf-t1--base at 657 DPI...
>   Running miktex-makemf.exe...
>   miktex-makemf: The Roboto-Light-lf-t1--base source file could not be found.
>
> Running ttf2pk.exe...
>   miktex-makepk: PK font Roboto-Light-lf-t1--base could not be created.
>    )
>   !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file Roboto-Light-lf-t1--base): Font Roboto-Light-
>   lf-t1--base at 657 not found

I tried running `updmap.exe` in a console, both as user and admin, but it didn't resolve the problem. An MWE is included below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{First slide}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Item
  \item Item
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** I just tried updating my packages and saw that the `roboto` package is obsolete. Could this have something to do with the error? Does this mean I can't use the font?

Comment: Which tex system do you use?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer MiKTeX 2.9 with the TeXworks editor.

Comment: I can use the font without problems (and my system is up-to-date). Perhaps the package has been renamed. Synchronize in the package manager (user and admin) in the repository menu your package database and run updates. Run also updmap.

Comment: Run from the command line ‘updmap’, to refresh the type1 files database.

Comment: Ever find a solution @Mangara ?

Comment: @Stormie Not with pdftex. I ended up switching to XeTeX, which was quite painless and made this very easy (it can use system fonts).

Comment: A similar error happens to me with pdfLaTeX.  I installed the package a few minutes ago, refreshed the file name database, and updated all the format files, but pdfLaTeX still gives these errors.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154998/64175

Comment: Works fine with TeXLive 2016

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by switching to xelatex

Comment: @samcarter I don't see how not finding a solution makes the question off-topic. Does this site have a policy of closing old unanswered questions?

Comment: @Mangara Please ignore the words "off-topic", most of the closed questions carry these words because it is the one reason where one can enter a custom close reason. As for the closure itself, from reading the comments I had the impression that the problem was solved, if you are still looking for an answer, feel free to vote for reopen. But before reopening, maybe report if Bernhard's suggestion worked.

Comment: @samcarter Okay, that makes sense. It's true that I'm not looking for a solution any more, as xelatex didn't have this issue. I'm pretty sure (but not 100%) that I tried Bernard's suggestion and it didn't help.