# Fontawesome won't render correctly while working on a moderncv

Tags: fonts, moderncv, fontawesome

I was working on my résumé using the moderncv template, when an odd error concerning fontawesome came up (I'll paste only the last lines of the log):

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/fontawesometwo/m/sl' undefined
(Font) using `U/fontawesometwo/m/n' instead on input line 94.
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for OMS+lmr on input line 94.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omslmr.fd"
File: omslmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OMS/lmr/m/sl' in size  not available
(Font) Font shape `OMS/lmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 94.
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (30.0pt):
Make it at least 51.952pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
[1
{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info: External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)  on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)  on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)  on input line 110.
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (30.0pt):
Make it at least 51.952pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
[2]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 162.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 162.
(C:\Users\lmdam\Desktop\moderncv\cv.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 162.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 162.
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `cv.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck) or use package `bookmark'.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `cv.out':
(rerunfilecheck) Before: 
(rerunfilecheck) After: 91D9B1A013BDBCD69BFACF90E673B69C;1735.
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
19772 strings out of 493921
326644 string characters out of 3144876
404671 words of memory out of 3000000
22816 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
73377 words of font info for 75 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
48i,21n,49p,10379b,425s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file FontAwesome--fontawesometwo): Font FontAwesome--f
ontawesometwo at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I don't really know what it means, but it seems to me that the problem is related to some "exotic" character. The only one I can spot on line 94 of my .tex file is the `š`.

I tried removing the character, but the error won't go away. Also, this is not the first draft of my cv, and the error had never happened before. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I just moved to Windows 10, but in any case I hope there's a solution to it.

Comment: Please check till the end of the log: there is some fatal error that straight blocks the rendering.

Comment: The font isn't installed properly.

Comment: Should I install the CTAN version or the GitHub one?

Comment: Which TeX installation are you using? Your installation's package manager should be able to install it (MiKTeX's or TeX Live's).

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the package, but I'm afraid the problem persists...

Comment: @cfr Judging by the posted log, MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: @Sverre Ta. I just realised that rather belatedly. So I'm guessing this is the common MiKTeX-fails-to-install-fonts-properly. I know there is a trick to completing the installation but can't remember what it is? (Running `updmap`? Running it from within the package manager?)

Comment: @cfr I tried running <code>updmap</code> and <code>initexmf --admin --mkmaps</code> from cmd, but nothing changed.

Comment: Try searching the site. I know almost nothing about Windows and have never used MikTeX. So I'm afraid I'm unlikely to be of much help. But this is a fairly common issue, it seems, and there are a lot of questions concerning it with comments or answers from people who *do* know what to do.

Comment: I've posted something in the chat room in the hope somebody who know MikTeX will take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with FontAwesome and struggled a lot with my new Windows 10 Installation, MiKTeX 2.9 and TexStudio. I also tried other things like running `initexmf --mkmaps` and `initexmf --update-fndb` or reinstalling MiKTeX or reinstalling the packages using MPM which didn't help me.

Here is what worked:

[miktex-makepk: PK font Alegreya-Regular-lf-t1--base could not be created](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154998/miktex-makepk-pk-font-alegreya-regular-lf-t1-base-could-not-be-created)

I replaced the `Map Alegreya.map` statement in that post with `Map FontAwesome.map` and then ran `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\updmap.exe` in an admin console (don't know if it's relevant).
After that, my file compiled fine using pdflatex.