# You have requested package `moderncvbodyi', but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'

Tags: miktex, moderncv, windows

I'm working with `moderncv` and keep getting the following warnings:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\moderncvheadii.sty: LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadii',               but the package provides `moderncvheadii'.
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\moderncvbodyi.sty: LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvbodyi',               but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'.
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\moderncvfooti.sty: LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvfooti',               but the package provides `moderncvfooti'.
PATH_TO_MY:FILE.tex:64: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/fontawesometwo/m/sl' undefined(Font)              using `U/fontawesometwo/m/n' instead on input line 64.
PATH_TO_MY:FILE.tex: LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

There was a lot more of such stuff before I did what dmtree explains [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263483/88423). Do you know how I can get rid of the last five warnings? I'm using Windows 10 with MikTex.

Comment: Regarding the package warnings: You should probably just [update your distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764). Regarding the last two warnings: They point to the same thing. You're trying to print a version of a [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) symbol that doesn't exist in that font; perhaps you're using the symbol in a heading or a title that is set in a specific font? If the visual display of the symbol seems okay, then you can ignore those warnings.

Comment: this is supposed to be fixed at source https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/issues/1  have you updated your miktex package?

Comment: I got the same error, but the error was part of hycolor. For me this worked:
1) Run "Miktex console" as administrator. 2) Find and install the package hycolor. 
After this everything workes fine.