# Moderncv package

Tags: miktex, moderncv

In order to write my CV, I am using moderncv.

1) I download the package moderncv 2.0.0 from CRAN : https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv

2) I dezziped the folder called moderncv. This folder contains :

- the moderncv.cls file,
- some .sty files,
- a folder that contains some examples, one of which is called template.tex.

3) I copied all the files contained in the example folder into the modercv folder in order to have all the files in the same folder.

4) I tried to run the template.tex file with Texmaker and Miktex 2.9 using pdflatex but it gives me : "Process exited with errors" but no error message appears, only some warnings messages.

Here are the warnings messages that appear :

[image: Warning messages in Texmaker]

The log file begins with :

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.5.31)  30 AUG 2016 10:07
>   entering extended mode
>   **./template.tex
>   (template.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
>   Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
>   (moderncv.cls
>   Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
>   ocument class

The log file ends with :

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file FontAwesome--fontawesomethree): Font FontAwesome-
>   -fontawesomethree at 600 not found
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Thanks in advance,

Anthony

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is your distribution? What does the .log file say?

Comment: That doesn't tell me what is your distribution. It seems clear your system doesn't find the type 1 version of `fontawesome`, since it tries to make bitmap fonts.

Comment: Possibly relevant http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263150/fontawesome-wont-render-correctly-while-working-on-a-moderncv

Comment: Excuse, I'm novice, how can I find the distribution?

Comment: Yes this is MiKTeX 2.9, I compile with pdflatex and the version number of moderncv is v2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at last there is a little bug in `moderncv` with the correct usage of `fontawesome`.  It depends on the useing of `casual` or `classic` or `banking` or ... and the way you compile: `pdflatex`, `lualatex` etc.

Because we have no MWE I can more or less only guess.

With the `moderncv` command `\moderncvicons` you can explicitly define the font you wants to be used for the symbols.  In your case, given by the error you mentioned, just add `\moderncvicons{marvosym}` to your preamble. Font `marvosym` can be used with `pdflatex`.