# Pdftex error in moderncv: FontAwesome--fontawesometwo at 600 not found

Tags: pdftex, moderncv, fontawesome

I am getting the abovementioned error when compiling a `moderncv` file in Texmaker. I recently switched to Windows 10.

I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154998/miktex-makepk-pk-font-alegreya-regular-lf-t1-base-could-not-be-created#_=_) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263150/fontawesome-wont-render-correctly-while-working-on-a-moderncv) but nothing worked. I am completely clueless what else I could try.

Do I need to install FontAwesome seperately as a font on my system?

Comment: I updated from Windows 8.1. I haven't installed MikTeX new but have updated all packages.

Comment: I did, I even restarted my computer afterwards. But I can try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem here.

I think, the problem is, that the 'casual' of modernvc uses the fontawesome package, which only works with lualatex or xelatex.

When using

```
\moderncvstyle{classic}
```

instead of

```
\moderncvstyle{casual}
```

it works for me.

See also this answer:
[How to use fontawesome-package in moderncv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193900/how-to-use-fontawesome-package-in-moderncv)

Since I like the 'casual' more than 'classic' I am still looking for a way to use it without fontawesome.

Comment: The more recent version [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) allows usage under pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks, you are right. I made an update of ALL my tex packages, and it suddenly works. Just updating fontawesome was not enough, i still got the "600" error.

Answer (score 2):

A manual activation using `\usepackage{fontawesome}` in the line just below `\documentclass` fixed the error for me.

Previously I tried reinstalling `moderncv` and `fontawesome` via Miktex-Console (Admin).
I use pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the font-awesome package. I needed to tell my TEX engine where to find the Map file for the font-awesome font. Running

```
updmap-sys --enable Map fontawesome.map
```

(inside /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/fontawesome/map)

fixed it for me.